# How can I store values into a vector using a loop?

Tags: matlab

I have the code:

```
for years = 1900:2000
  temp = T(year == years & month == 1);
  mt = mean(temp);
  fprintf('The mean of January through 1900-2000 is %2.3f\n', mt)
end
```

This prints me the mean temperatures for Jan through those years.

But I would like to store those values in a vector, and when I tried adding `mt = [mt]` in the for loop, it only gives me the last mean value, also in my workspace mt is equal to only the last mean value that is printed. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you were trying to do is

```
mt = [mt, mean(temp)]
```

which will work. However, this is an inefficient way to go in MATLAB as it is growing the matrix in the loop.

A better way to go is to preallocate a matrix before hand so

```
years = 1900:2000;
mt = zeros(numel(years),1)
for yearnum = 1:numel(years);
    temp = T(year == years(yearnum) & month == 1);
    mt(yearnum) = mean(temp);
end
fprintf('The mean of January through 1900-2000 is %2.3f\n', mean(mt))
```

Also note that I have taken your `fprintf` line out of the loop.

An even better way to go in MATLAB is to use a vectorized approach instead of a loop but this will depend on the structure of your matrix `T`.

Comment: Thank you, I see, do you mean performance-wise it is inefficient?

Comment: @user5983828 yes, perfomance wise. Look up growing a matrix in a loop and preallocation in MATLAB and you'll find plenty of explanations.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, one question though, what is the purpose of nume1?

Comment: [`numel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) is short for *number of elements*. Think of it as being very similar to the length of your `years` vector. I used it just to make the code more general. In your case you can replace `numel(years)` with `101`. But what if you decided to change you range to `years = 1950:2000` or `years = 1900:10:2000`? Then you would have to recalculate and change that `101` but by using `numel` you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you so much, stupid me thought that it was a 1 not a lowecase L, but numel worked for me.